# RecyclerView inside RecyclerView displaying wrong data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an adapter that holds another recyclerview inside, when I load data to this adapter I also load the data for the inner adapter , it is populated but is not populated correctly, when I scroll it populates the items (also wrongly) but when inflated not

```
class OrdersAdapter(private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

    private val innerAdapter by lazy { OrdersInnerAdapter(context) }

    ...

     inner class MainViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<Order>(itemView) {
            override fun bind(item: Order, position: Int) {

                itemView.user_name.text = item.userName

                itemView.rv_order_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                itemView.rv_order_items.adapter = innerAdapter
                innerAdapter.setItems(item.cartList)

    }
```

Now this is my inner adapter

```
class OrdersInnerAdapter(val context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>(){

    private var cartList = mutableListOf<Cart>()

 fun setItems(cartList:MutableList<Cart>){
        this.cartList = cartList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    } 

 ....

  inner class OrdersInnerViewHolder(itemView: View):BaseViewHolder<Cart>(itemView){
        override fun bind(item: Cart, position: Int) {
            itemView.item_name.text = item.productName
            itemView.item_qty.text = "Quantity: ${item.qty}"
            itemView.item_price.text = "$${item.price.times(item.qty)}.00"
        }
    }
```

This is my use case

[image]

But items inside the inner adapter are loaded wrongly, any idea?

Comment: What is wrong with the loaded items? I mean is it repeating the old items or what? Try setting a new `OrdersInnerAdapter` to each item in `MainViewHolder`

Comment: Wow, it was that simple !!, thansk !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class OrdersAdapter(private val context: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

 inner class MainViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<Order>(itemView) {
        override fun bind(item: Order, position: Int) {

            itemView.user_name.text = item.userName

            itemView.rv_order_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            val innerAdapter = OrdersInnerAdapter(context)
            itemView.rv_order_items.adapter = innerAdapter
            innerAdapter.setItems(item.cartList)

}
```

And you don't need `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `setItems` of `OrdersInnerAdapter`. It would be

```
fun setItems(cartList:MutableList<Cart>){
    this.cartList = cartList // You can also move this to constructor to get rid of extra method.
}
```